# Windows borderless OpenGL window with strange tabbing issue

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, opengl

I want to create a borderless, fullscreen OpenGL window with the Windows API. This is seen in many games so that you can quickly tab between your game and another application.

My problem is that when I create my window (which works) and I tab out, it does tab out, because I see my cursor change to the text cursor for my text editor, but the screen is still completely red from my OpenGL application, thus I cannot see anything.

The issue however is resolved when I set a breakpoint (Visual Studio) in the main loop (or before the main loop but after window creation), before I swap the buffers, and let it resume after that. Below is my mainloop. I am using my own window class.

```
while(window.Running())
{
    window.PollEvents();

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    window.SwapBuffers();
    Sleep(10);
}
```

My question is: What happens when I pause my application before the swapping of buffers that makes the window behave differently (for me correctly)?

The inside of `window.SwapBuffers()` is the following:

```
void GLWindowImpWin32::swapBuffers()
{
    SwapBuffers(handleDeviceContext);
}
```

Where `handleDeviceContext` is my `HDC`.

Also pressing the Windows button does not visually bring up the taskbar in front of the application.

Here's my minimized source code which behaves the same as my original code, it also works if you put a breakpoint before swapping the buffers. If you are compiling, don't forget to link to `opengl32.lib`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>

WNDCLASSEX windowClass;
HWND handleWindow;
HDC handleDeviceContext;
HGLRC handleGLRenderingContext;
bool running = false;

// set this to your screen size
const int windowWidth = 1680;
const int windowHeight = 1050;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        {
            handleDeviceContext = GetDC(hWnd);

            PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
            {
                sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
                1,                              
                PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |            
                PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |            
                PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,       
                PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                  
                32,                             
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,               
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0, 0, 0, 0,
                16,                             
                8,                              
                0,
                PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
                0,
                0, 0, 0
            };

            int pixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(handleDeviceContext, &pfd);
            SetPixelFormat(handleDeviceContext, pixelFormat, &pfd);

            handleGLRenderingContext = wglCreateContext(handleDeviceContext);

            wglMakeCurrent(handleDeviceContext, handleGLRenderingContext);

            running = true;

            break;
        }
    case WM_DESTROY:
    case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            wglMakeCurrent(handleDeviceContext, NULL);
            wglDeleteContext(handleGLRenderingContext);

            running = false;

            break;
        }
    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE prevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    memset(&windowClass, 0, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    windowClass.cbSize          = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    windowClass.style           = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    windowClass.cbClsExtra      = 0;
    windowClass.cbWndExtra      = 0;
    windowClass.hInstance       = hInstance;
    windowClass.hIcon           = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    windowClass.hIconSm         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    windowClass.hCursor         = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    windowClass.hbrBackground   = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszMenuName    = NULL;
    windowClass.lpszClassName   = "GLWindowClass";
    windowClass.lpfnWndProc     = WndProc;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&windowClass))
    {
        return false;
    }

    DWORD windowStyleEx = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
    DWORD windowStyle = WS_POPUP;

    handleWindow = CreateWindow(
        "GLWindowClass",
        "title",
        windowStyle | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,    
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        windowWidth,
        windowHeight,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    if(!handleWindow)
    {
        return false;
    }

    handleDeviceContext = GetDC(handleWindow);

    ShowWindow(handleWindow, SW_SHOW);

    while(running)
    {
        MSG msg;

        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        SwapBuffers(handleDeviceContext);
        Sleep(10);
    }

    PostQuitMessage(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe your issue your issue is related to the handling of fullscreen GL windows by Windows ; related to a similar issue I still have, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378918/modal-dialogs-opened-by-a-fullscreen-opengl-window-on-windows-7-are-not-showing

Comment: Yes, my problem seems to be very similar if not the same. Although I still find it strange that I don't experience any problem if I put a breakpoint after window creation, so there has to be a way for it to work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buffer swapping is not enough. You need to tell Windows that you have switched windows. In order to get the 'other application' to show its screen, Windows needs to know that your application is no longer on top and the other application should be brought to the front, and allowed to repaint.

EDIT/REWRITE:
Now that you have provided the source code for a sample, and I have compiled and tested the code, I make the following observations.

1. I cannot reproduce the problem. On Windows 8 dual monitor, the main monitor is completely replaced by a red panel, but Alt+Tab and the Windows key behave normally. The second monitor is unaffected. I have no idea whether it's the Windows 8, the dual monitor or something else that makes the difference.
2. The code as provided assumes a 1680x1050 monitor. Mine is 1920x1080. The screen height and width must exactly match for the program to work as intended. I edited the code to match.
3. The DC being used is from a window handle. This means that all OpenGL drawing will be inside the window. However, it will not respect the NC boundaries -- it will overwrite the entire window.
4. There is no WM_PAINT handler, so Windows may assume that the window has never been painted and the entire client area is invalid. The DefWindowProc willpaint and validate the NC area (if any).

Apart from my belief that this is where the problem is, I don't think I can help further. You might want to try on a different version of Windows, or a dual monitor system. You might want to try adding a paint handler (it just needs to call BeingPaint/EndPaint).

Comment: I will put a shortly put a link in my OP with my stripped down source code.

Comment: How are you supposed to 'tell' "Windows that you have switched windows" ? Care to elaborate ? AFAIK Alt-TAB is supposed to work without the cooperation of the current application.

Comment: See edit. Not really, not if you're painting outside a window. You will get a WM_ACTIVATEAPP and you will probably have to handle it.

Comment: OK, I have now provided a link with minial code that behaves the same (http://pastebin.com/gKuwd3w0), this is also in my OP.

Comment: Sharp of you to notice the screen size. I should have left a comment there. I tested the program on another computer today and it worked fine, so I am assuming it is just my computer that is evil. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: No probblem. What OS are you running it on?

Comment: Both are Windows 7, but the laptop on which I made it originally has a few driver issues I found out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps, but try to change `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` to `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`

I think this might be interesting. Though I don't know a lot about your case:

> Depth Buffer
>
> The depth buffer stores a depth value for each pixel. As described in
>   "A Hidden-Surface Removal Survival Kit" in Chapter 5, depth is usually
>   measured in terms of distance to the eye, so pixels with larger
>   depth-buffer values are overwritten by pixels with smaller values.
>   This is just a useful convention, however, and the depth buffer's
>   behavior can be modified as described in "Depth Test." The depth
>   buffer is sometimes called the z buffer (the z comes from the fact
>   that x and y values measure horizontal and vertical displacement on
>   the screen, and the z value measures distance perpendicular to the
>   screen).

Source:

> http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter10.html

Also, I think you should show what happens in window.SwapBuffers();

Sorry if this doesn't work, but you should try it at least.

**EDIT:**

I really think the problem is with the Sleep() function. I tried it and it stopped drawing(though still working).

Comment: I tried replacing the glClear call with your call but sadly with no result. I updated my post show what happens in window.SwapBuffers

Comment: Try using glGetError() and search around the result (if any).

Comment: Yes, I get a red screen so OpenGL works correctly, but I cannot succesfully Alt+Tab without having a break in my code.

Comment: I still don't understand your question clearly. The problem could also be because of Sleep().  I have just tried it on one of my OGL apps and before and after swapping the buffers, sleep makes my app stop drawing.

Comment: OK, so when I let my application run normally I get it running in fullscreen, but when I Alt+Tab it does change control to the other program, but it doesn't update the screen so it still looks red. However if I put the breakpoint in my code everything works normally.

Comment: Try deleting Sleep(10);